# asp.net debugging on PROD server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, https

I have a new website almost ready for prime time.
I'm incorporating MSN/Hotmail/Windows Live importing of Email addresses.
From my local PC, I get an error message that says that MSN requires a secure connection.
I have my SSL installed on my Prod server.
Since I'm not live yet, I've installed VS2008 on the Prod server and would like to debug under https...But I only see http://localhost/xxx when I run the app from w/in VS.
I've tried attaching to the w3wp.exe & the WebDev.WebServer.exe processes and then trying to debug when I use my http://www.actualURLName.com address.
I'd appreciate any help - even if I'm way off base.
If there's another way of debugging (thru HTTPS) running my app on the Prod server, I'd appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: what is the address that you are using to connect to MSN?

Comment: This is from the Contact Grabber software...Seems that Google/Yahoo/MSN have gone oAuth...It just seems that requiring a secure line is only req'd from MSN.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug remotely, from your development machine attaching to the production machine (the menu option is housed under the "Debug" menu, I believe); Microsoft have a couple of articles on this over at MSDN, like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx).

Which version of Visual Studio are you using? This is not supported with Express editions.